# Error al cambiar el nombre de la columna email a correo en login laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quiero cambiar el nombre de la columna "email" a "correo" en el login predeterminado de laravel, pero me esta dando problemas, llevo un tiempo mirando esto y dentro de esta funcion, que es la que se llama cuando hago el login. (Esto esta situado en el trait AuthenticatesUsers)

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validateLogin($request);


        $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

        if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

        if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
        }


        if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

me da fallo esta linea.

```
 if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
```

y el error es este

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 673: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = 2@2.com limit 1)
```

Como digo lo unico que he cambiado es en mi columna "email" dentro de la tabla users, la he llamado correo, sé que podria renombrar esa columna y todo funcionaria, pero quiero saber por que falla en caso de que se cambien las columnas.

Al usar el comando make::auth(), la peticion post que hace para logearse va al metodo login que he puesto anteriormente, por lo que he intentado sobreescribir ese metodo colocandolo con una pequeña modificacion en el controlador "CONTROLLER",y me da un error

```
Declaration of Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers::login() should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::login(App\Http\Controllers\Request $request)
```

La vista login, es la que viene por defecto con laravel,
Es decir, esta

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> </div>
```

Sé que podria usar un login manual usando Auth::attemp(), pero me gustaria saber si hay algun modo de cambiar el nombre de cualquier columna para que sea validada por el login que viene por defecto con laravel.

Mi migracion de la tabla users esta asi.

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('correo')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->enum('genero', array('f','m'));
            $table->string('bio');
            $table->string('api_token',60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

--------------------EDITADO--------------------------

Por cierto, he probado a modificar este metodo, que esta situado en el mismo trait de login

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
```

por este

```
 protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'correo' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
```

y no me da ningún tipo de error, pero me manda constamente a la misma pagina, me recarga la pagina sin errores, pero no consigue iniciar session.

----------------------------EDITADO 2--------------------------------
Respondiendo a Shaz

Eso ya lo habia probado con identico resultado, lo habia añadido tanto en el authcontroller como modificado en el trait AuthenticatesUsers

De este modo

```
public function loginUsername()
    {
        return 'correo';

    }
```

y también asi

```
 public function loginUsername()
    {

       return property_exists($this, 'username') ? 'correo' : 'email';
    }
```

Es lo mismo, ni siquiera hace las validaciones, lo primero que salta se este error

```
 QueryException in Connection.php line 673: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = 2@2.com)
```

He probado a hacerlo de forma manual, es decir asi (metodo authController)

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [

            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',

            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

      public function login(Request $request)
       { 
             $v =  $this->validator($request->all()); 
          if($v->fails()):
              return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($v->errors());  
        endif;


        if (\Auth::attempt(['correo' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) :
                    return view('welcome');
       else:



             return view('auth.login');

       endif;

       }
```

Vuelvo a recordar que el campo "email" de la validacion es el campo que enviamos en las vistas, el campo que me da error es el campo de la base de datos que es correo.

Resumiendo, si esto lo dejo asi

```
public function loginUsername()
        {

           return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
        }
```

Me da el error de columna email no encontrada en la base de datos
y si lo cambio asi

```
 public function loginUsername()
        {

           return property_exists($this, 'username') ? 'correo' : 'email';
        }
```

Cuando le doy al submit me vuelve a enviar a la misma pagina sin ningún error.

Comment: ¿qué versión de Laravel utilizas?

Comment: Ahora mismo, Laravel 5.2.31

Comment: Añadidas lineas en post principal debajo de -------EDITADO------

Comment: Aunque no cambia nada, tienes un error (de lógica) en la forma como utilizas el operador ternario, puede ser una buena idea que revises como funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo lo que pasa es que el registerController que trae por defecto espera es el campo email, lo mejor es que si quieres cambiar el nombre de la columna te revises el codigo fuente de register controller que esta en la ruta vendor/laravel/framework/Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers

lo copies lo pegas en el controlador de la ruta app/Http/Controllers/Auth/Registercontroller y luego acomodes a tu antojo.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas sobreescribir en tu controlador de login/auth el método `loginUserName` de `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`.

Este es el código pertinente que debes modificar a tu gusto (en tu controlador): https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L191

```
/**
 * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function loginUsername()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
}
```

Comment: Añadida respuesta en post principal

Comment: Ya ví tu otro punto, voy a revisar. En varios proyectos lo he cambiado sin problema, solo que hace rato no trabajo con L5.2 y no recuerdo el método exacto.